# If I buy a new screen, can I fix this issue in my phone?

Tags: screen, xiaomi, broken-screen

I have a xiaomi mi 9t pro (I guess it's also named k20pro), it's that 2019 xiaomi phone with moving front camera, no notch. And for the last 2 months I got this pink-blurry-stain in the bottom-right side of my screen. It's slowly growing, already making it harder to use the phone. Also it has something like a "blind spot" for the touchscreen, a little above the keyboard (fortunatelly). I was wondering if I could fix all these issues by replacing this phone's screen.

The technicians in my city say they can do the job, but I'll have to buy the replacement by myself, and I'm a bit worried to buy the wrong screen. It's very easy to find, but I would like to be sure that I'm buying the right item. In example: [This seller](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32966408658.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4ea731baRgp6ov&algo_pvid=c6162b22-a422-457f-a892-8a2646cfef6c&algo_expid=c6162b22-a422-457f-a892-8a2646cfef6c-2&btsid=0bb0624216145137327916101e3bb5&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) shows the correct names for the phone, he has amoled blue frame (my phone version/model). Is it all I need?

Thanks in advance =]

[image: another one]
[image: stain screen]

Comment: To me it looks like a video decoding problem. The bad thing is: if I am right, then a display switch won't help. The good thing: you have some good chance to fix it on a software way.

Comment: Sorry, the problem isn't the video thumbnail, this is just a random screen I've used. The problem is the pink stain in the phone's bottom-right corner. It shows up in every screen: The launcher, google now, boot screen, lock screen, games etc.

Comment: physical damage. replace screen

Comment: btw i recommend to set up [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc) as kind of emergency access immediately. this requires usb-debugging from developer options